# Exists the full stack of the Regular Expression in Cypher language?

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I had been checking the Neo4j documentation and until now, I was not be able to find anything else than the simple wildcard `'*'` to be used in **Cypher**.

My question is: Exists the posibility to use real Regular Expressions  like `'\d','\w','+','[0..9]'`, etc... any example to use them ???

*I'm trying to do something `[0..9]+-[0..9]{2}` to match with 123-12 numbers into the field.*

In case that it's not possible to use the full stack, someone knows if it's in the path for future releases?

Thanks in advance for your responses
Antonio

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to use Java regular expressions for property matching. E.g.:

```
MATCH (n)
WHERE n.name =~ '[orphseuM]{8}'
RETURN n;
```

See the result in neo4j console:
http://console.neo4j.org/?id=5ty5kv

Comment: Perfect, my problem was to use correctly the statements with more slashes.  `MATCH (s) WHERE s.name=~'[\\d]*-[\\d]*-.*' RETURN s.name;` is working with `123-23-{anything}` ... but it's not working with other standard regex like `[0..9]`

Comment: What do you mean by "standard regex"? You may use [0-9] syntax for ranges of characters. See javadoc for java regular expression http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html

Comment: Ok, thanks Frant, it was a mistake from my side using twice points ... X-D